# Wordpress - Add Fullscreen hero image on designated blogroll template page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, fullscreen, blogs

I'm using custom page templates for every page of our portfolio website. The blog page is not the landing page but an interior page.  I'm able to put a custom hero image on every page template but having issues with adding on for the blog page.  I'm using the content.php page to designate the layout based on the landing page with all articles listed and also for the single post layout page.

I can't get a fullscreen hero div to work within the loop. If i do add it to content.php it repeats endlessly down the page.  Adding a custom header.php doesn't work because the content.php is already adding that content within the container div. Anyone know which template file is calling  in the content.php template so i can add the hero image there perhaps?

```
<?php endif; // is_single() ?>

<?php if ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <section class="content-interior">
```

If i put this in the else statement within content.php it just does not work.  Any advice to add a fullscreen hero image to jsut the main blogroll page which i'm just pulling in the latest ten titles and associated category tag?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

for those who are curious, it ended up working by adding the section for the hero in the index.php file on my theme

```
get_header(""); ?>

<div class="landing-page-hero blog">

    <section class="landing-page-hero-content">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

                    <div class="landing-page-intro">

                        <h1>
                            Blog
                        </h1>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </section>

</div>
```

And that worked for me.